# How do I rotate the viewport, without leaving the x/y-plane?

Tags: 3d-view, constraints, axis

I'm looking at an object, sometimes very close, to check visual heights. I'm in orthographic view, straight front.

Now I want to rotate slowly to the left/right side, without leaving the xy-plane (while constructing, not for animation). But every slightest move of the mouse kicks me into space, and I can't check exactly.
I know rotating while pressing alt key. But this is very crude snapping. I need to rotate smoothly or at least in about 5° steps.
I'd like to press <kbd>Z</kbd> key, and then keeping movement always stable in xy-plane (like on grap or rotate). It also could help on other axes, or even local coordinates.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated based on the comment:**

The option you look for is the "Orbit left" using the <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and "Orbit Right" using <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> respectively. *At least in my logic that is the only way to rotate the viewport(as in the title of the question) and is not leaving the xy-plane. Not sure how "Roll and Orbit is different here as the result seems to be the same.*
[image]

The increase or decrease in angle is set default to 15 degree in the preferences here:
[image]

Setting the **Rotation Angle** to 1.0, would result in the "Orbiting" to be a lot smoother.

Here a little visual demonstration:
[image]

Happy Blending

Comment: That's what im looking for! But not ShiftNum4-6, but plain Num4-6. Almost perfect! (By mouse would have been nicer, but numpad is a cool solution.) Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer, while i still do not know why **Rolling** and **Orbiting** seems to result in the same visual result. Also, please consider to accept the answer should it be solving your question.

Comment: Rolling and orbiting are not doing the same at (e.g.) FrontView/Num1. Only on Front/Num1 or side View/Num3 xy-plane collapses to 1 line. (Similar movement to camera Suzanne in other answer, whereas your visualisation is in TopView.)

Comment: True, only in top view they result in a similar visual result (speaking of Num4/6 and Shift+Num4/6).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to rotate the plane without leaving xy plane is go to front view by pressing <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> and when you are there press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> it will automatically correct your perspective to a XY plane view

If by chance its not aligned in XY view for you to rotate then you just have to press the <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> to align it and then when it comes in XY view.

Now you can rotate it by just pressing <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>.

If you having problem adjusting your viewport in single step make sure first that you are in front view. As it will be easier to set in front view rather than orthographic view.